# Run another function only when the previous function is finished in python

Tags: python, multithreading, function, locking

I have 4 functions:

1. firstfunc()
2. secondfunc()
3. thirdfunc()
4. forthfunc()

I want to run these functions sequentially(order doesn't matter) and not together, I need the functions to wait till one of them completes the task, and then another one should start executing.

Each function returns a different value which is then to be stored in a variable and later used for further data processing. How can this be done in python? I am kinda a novice in python.

Comment: If you need them run sequentially, why are you bothering with muliprocessing?  Just call `firstfunc()` then `secondfunc()`, ....  There is some context here that's missing.

Answer (score 1):

Programming language execute from top unless stated otherwise by the use of conditional statements. What you want to achieve here is pretty the way you arrange it.

Execute the first one followed by the second and so on.

Comment: I don't think this is the question of the op. I believe that what he actually wants is to only execute a function after another one completed, not using the traditional `queue` method but rather using something like a asynchronous/await that is present in some other languages, like JavaScript. The thing is, I am also in need of this  and has nothing to do with conditional states nor sequential functions execution.